# for every continuous function prove that $\int_0^{x} (t^3)f(t^2)dt = 0.5 \int_0^{x^2} tf(t)dt$

Tags: integration

for every continuous function prove that $\int_0^{x} (t^3)f(t^2)dt = 0.5 \int_0^{x^2} tf(t)dt$

I thought about the Fundamental theorem of calculus but dont really know how to advance from there.

Comment: Oh god please you have to use proper MathJAx.

Comment: my bad, now its good

Comment: Hint: the derivative of LHS is equal to the derivative of RHS, and LHS is equal to RHS for $x =0$.

Comment: In the integral in the left side, use the substitution $t^2=u$ and then interchange $u$ with $t$ after the substitution.

Comment: I cannot help you till you show more effort. My answer was downvoted. Why not show exactly what you've done with the FTC?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just [a variable change](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html#:%7E:text=The%20change%20of%20variables%20theorem%20takes%20this%20infinitesimal%20knowledge%2C%20and,in%20area%2C%20bit%20by%20bit.&text=is%20a%20smooth%20map%20which,preserving%20diffeomorphism%20of%20the%20boundaries.) $u = t^2$, then $\dfrac{1}{2}du = t dt$, when $t=0$, $u=0$ and and when $t=x$, $u = x^2$.

$\int_0^{x} (t^3)f(t^2)dt = \int_0^{x} (t^2)f(t^2)tdt =  \dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2} uf(u)du.$